# Отследить неверные попытки ввода графического ключа

Tags: android, безопасность, shell

Ради спортивного интереса решил выполнить одну вещь, нужно отследить момент, когда графический ключ введен неверно **на уровне Shell скрипта**. Поиски каких-то файлов ни к чему не привели. При вводе верного ключа после неверных меняется только время последнего изменения файла `/data/system/device_policies.xml`. Если ключ ввести верно сразу, то ничего с этим файлом не происходит. Как отследить именно момент ввода неверного ключа?

P. S CyanogenMod 13

Ключ 4*4, системная настройка, никакого другого софта. Есть вариант декомпилировать приложение настроек и внести изменения на уровне smali но это может закончиться неуспешно, может есть способ на уровне ФС? Какие-то `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: зачем же декомпилировать то, что собрано из публично доступных исходников? (*P. S CyanogenMod 13*)

Comment: @alexander barakin, ох, точно :) сейчас поищу в коде что-то связанное с неверным вводом

Comment: @alexander barakin, знать бы название класса локера :D